# histogram of RandomInteger is wrong at boundary

Tags: histograms

The problem is easy to reproduce.

Try

```
Histogram[RandomInteger[{-205, 205}, 10000]]
```

I got

[image]

What is wrong with the boundary bar? They supposed to be the same height as other bars.

Ps: I am using Mathematica 10.4

Comment: `HistogramList@RandomInteger[{-205, 205}, 10000]` or x axis will tell you that the first and last bins starts at `+-220`

Comment: Workaround: `Histogram[RandomInteger[{-205, 205}, 10000], {-205, 205, 20}]`

Comment: @Kuba That makes thing clear. Thank you Kuba

Comment: @Karsten7. This works, Thank you Karsten7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things worth explained here.

1. The bins in Histogram and its family functions are all left closed, right open. Integer data, most of the times, shows this behavior.
2. As @Karsten7 suggested, specifying bin spec `{-205, 205, 20}` will work on this case. Histogram, by default, is trying to find "nice" bin delimiters, thus `{-220, 220, 20}`, which goal is to cover all data points and to give a reasonable number of bars, besides nice cut-offs.